# In a Document set Content type columns does not reflect in side the document set

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, designer-workflow, document-set

When i created a new document set content type i am trying to update the metadata in the content type using a workflow.It is updating content on document set but is not reflecting inside the document set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the content type Document Set in the library settings you should be able to sync all the columns you need in the document set settings. From there you can choose which columns you want to sync.